# How to reuse the html code in every html page?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Let say I have the code as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#overlay_form{
    position: absolute;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    padding: 10px;
    background: white;
    width: 270px;
    height: 190px;
}
#pop{
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    width: 65px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    //open popup
    $("#pop").click(function(){
        $("#overlay_form").fadeIn(1000);
        positionPopup();
    });

    //close popup
    $("#close").click(function(){
        $("#overlay_form").fadeOut(500);
    });
});

//position the popup at the center of the page
function positionPopup(){
    if(!$("#overlay_form").is(':visible')){
        return;
    }
    $("#overlay_form").css({
        left: ($(window).width() - $('#overlay_form').width()) / 2,
        top: ($(window).width() - $('#overlay_form').width()) / 7,
        position:'absolute'
    });
}

//maintain the popup at center of the page when browser resized
$(window).bind('resize',positionPopup);

</script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#" id="pop" >PopUp</a>
<br />
<form id="overlay_form" style="display:none">
<h2> Put your contents here..</h2>
<label>Username: </label><input type="text" name="username" /><br /><br />
<label>Password: </label><input type="text" name="password" /><br /><br />
<input type="button" value="Login" />
<a href="#" id="close" >Close</a>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

This is a popup dialog example. Let say I want to use this dialog in all my webpages (a.html, b.html, c.html and etc), what is the best and easiest way to make the code above to be reusable? Because I think that to copy paste the 'overlay_form' into every html pages is not reasonable.

I am still at the beginning level in Javascript, so to create a jQuery plugin for this is too hard for me. That's why I would like to seek for other ways to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could put your code in a different `.html` file and load it with `.load()` http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$('#targetid').load('somewhere/a.html'); // loads the .html in the #targetid
```

Comment: I've been looking into code reuse and like the jQuery approach the best, BUT, I'm having issues applying my css to the loaded content. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: how well this a.html will be indexed by GoogleBot?

Answer (score 4):

Best practice if you want to re-use the code multiple times is to place all your jQuery code into an external `.js` file, place all your CSS into an external style sheet, and reference those files from each page.

E.g. for the CSS, in a file named `style.css`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

and for the jQuery in a file named `jQueryFunctions.js`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQueryFunctions.js"></script>
```

In regard to including the same HTML code on different pages, one of the simplest ways I can think of would be to use the PHP [include()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function. [Here's a very simple one-page tutorial](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/website-design/using-php-and-mysql/using-php-include-function) on re-using HTML forms on multiple pages using it.

Answer (score 2):

put all of your reusable code in a html document and call it to the page using the following php code:

```
<?php include("example.html") ?>
```

Comment: Don't think he's using `php`, he didn't tag it.

Comment: I got the answer what I was looking for, thank you user1102285.

Answer (score 0):

[Modest HTML](https://github.com/goalzen/modest) does this.

It looks like this:

**main.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <include>overlayForm</include>
  </head>
  <body>
    <overlayForm/>
  </body>
</html>
```

**overlayForm.xml**

```
<form style="display:none">
  <h2> Put your contents here..</h2>
  <label>Username: </label><input type="text" name="username" /><br /><br />
  <label>Password: </label><input type="text" name="password" /><br /><br />
  <input type="button" value="Login" />
  <a href="#" id="close" >Close</a>
</form>
```