# How to use the same HTML-Block on multiple websites?

Tags: html, codeblocks

I'm just coding my first Website and it has lots of Subsites. Every Website needs the same code-block at some point. This code block just contains HTML code. Is it possible to make a data with this code-block and import it on every website? My goal is: If I have to update the code-block I just want to do it once.

The code-block is a sidebar and looks like this:

```html
<div id="sidebar">
    <div class="inner">
        <nav id="menu">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="../index.html">Homepage</a></li>
            <li>
                <span class="opener">SomeName</span>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="../Somestuff/SomeWebsite.html">Main Page</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are 1000 ways to do this. Use php, java or whatever server language you want to include files in another.

Comment: You literally just described the whole idea behind React.js. Might be daunting to someone just starting off but worth looking into. Link----> https://reactjs.org/

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852401/how-to-reuse-the-html-code-in-every-html-page)  could be useful. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636528/how-do-i-load-an-html-page-in-a-div-using-javascript) post asks about similar things.

Also frameworks (such as Vue, React, Angular...) are used for such purposes.

Comment: So i tried <script> $( "#sidebar" ).load( "sidebar.html" ); </script> <ol id="sidebar"></ol> with the code shown above in sidebar.html. But it does not work

Comment: First of all, try to reverse it (`<ol id="sidebar"></ol><script> $( "#sidebar" ).load( "sidebar.html" ); </script>`) and check that jquery is loaded correctly.

Comment: I reversed it -> nothing happened. I'm loading jquery with <script src="jquery/jquery.js"></script> at the end of the code before <\body>

Comment: Load jquery earlier - in `<head>`

Comment: I tried, nothing happend. I loaded it at the beginning of head and body. :c

Comment: Ah i see ( sorry I'm a HTML noob ). The access has been blocked. "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https." Does my sidebar.html has the wrong format?

Comment: Checkout [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/190266/why-chrome-blocks-ajax-locally) question.

Comment: @Titanlord I've edited the answer a bit (the second link seems to be better solution)

Answer (score 0):

Which extensions are your file? Php or html?
Cause if it’s php you can make a new file (for your example: nav.php) and then in every subsites you need to do:
require path_to_your_nav.php

If it’s html, i dont know there is no solution yet

Answer (score 0):

You could make a simple JS function that sets the innerHTML of a already existing HTML element. And put the function in an external JS file.

example below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <!-- link external js file with create element function -->
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function createElement(){
            //Get parent container
            const parent = document.getElementById('sidebar');

            //Set inner html 
            parent.innerHTML = 
            `<div id="sidebar">
                <div class="inner">
                    <nav id="menu">
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="../index.html">Homepage</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="opener"SomeName</span>
                            <ul>
                            <li><a href="../Somestuff/SomeWebsite.html">Main Page</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>`;
        }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="sidebar">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            createElement();
        </script>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How can i unclude this to my external file?

Comment: <script src="script.js (your external js file)>". This is pretty basic stuff. Link----->https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp